# How can i redirect to another page using the ajax function without having that page called back to the ajax function argument target div?

Tags: python-2.7, web2py

I am using the ajax function to take a registration key from a user on a textfield on a view to a controller, what is supposed to happen is that if the registration key is valid the user should be redirected to another page allowing them normal application usage. The controller function doing the redirecting wont redirect to a new page instead it opens the page that the user should be redirected to in the target div where it should display the Incorrect Code message. How can i override this occurrence and be able to redirect the user to an entirely new page if the Registration Key is correct as intended & still be able to display the Incorrect Code message in the relevant div when its called for?

THE VIEW

```
<div id="code">
  <input id="regcode"  maxlength="10" type="text" class="field" name="regCode" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="ajax('product_key_entry', ['regCode'], 'regCodeTarget')" placeholder="Enter Product Key"/><br />
                <div id="regCodeTarget"></div>
```

THE CONTROLLER

```
def reg_key_entry():
    key_exists = not db(db.regKeys.regKey == request.vars.regCode).isempty()
    if key_exists:
        #A used reg key should get deleted so that it cant be used twice
        db(db.regKeys.regKey == request.vars.regCode).delete()
        redirect(URL('index'))
    else:
        return DIV("INCORRECT PRODUCT KEY", _id="regCodeTarget", _style="color: white; border: solid 1px red; width: 160px; background-color: red; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; border-radius:5px;")
```

What i was hoping to achieve was to have the user get redirected to new defined page when the correct registration key is entered but instead of that now when the registration key is correct the page they are supposed to get redirected to gets called to the target div in the same page they are supposed to get redirected from!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
redirect(URL('index'), client_side=True)
```

With `client_side=True`, instead of the server returning a 303 redirect response, it returns a special header, and the client-side Javascript handles the redirect (by changing `window.location`).

See http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#HTTP-and-redirect.